# How to use controller function in factory?

Tags: angularjs

```
myapp.controller("controller1",function(factory_name){
     function abc(){
           //code of function 
 })

 myapp.factor(""factory_name",function(){
  return {
    'name': function(){
       i want to use function abc here
    }
}
})
```

I want to use controller function into the factory.As I cant use $scope I am not able to use. I have searched many pages but failed with all solution I have found.

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: I would suggest using json module

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to output to look like but to get you started you can get the keys and values of the dict as separate lists. Use `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()`.